# Excel.Range.Find method

Tags: c#, interop, ms-office

I am using Excel interop object and trying to find a date in a specified range by below method

```
Excel.Range rngFind = WS.get_Range(strFromRange, strToRange).Find(strFind, Type.Missing,
                Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
                Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false, false, false);
```

but i get rngFind as null always my strFind = "Sep-08" i tried with both Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas and Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues

my excel file looks like this

```
Sep-08  Oct-08  Nov-08  Dec-08  Jan-09  Feb-09  Mar-09  Apr-09  May-09  Jun-09  Jul-09
```

where as wheni click on Sep-08 cell i get `9/1/2008` in the formula field in Excel
i have also tried searching for 9/1/2008 but it varies system by system as per the RegionalSettings Date format...

Please help me. basically i am doing to get the cell address of the finding string

Comment: Are you using the Primary Interop Assemblies provided by Microsoft or simply pointing to the Excel dlls and letting Visual Studio generate the proxy for you? Also what version of Excel are you interoping with?

Comment: What values are you passing for strFromRange and strToRange?

Answer (score 5):

Using Office 2007, Interop generated directly from Visual Studio.  I used the following code to find the cell in question:

```
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

object False = false;
object True = true;

_Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();

Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks._Open(@"C:\tmp\StackOverflow.xlsx",False, False,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,False,False,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,False,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,True);

_Worksheet ws = (_Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];

string from = "A1";
string to = "B1";

Range rng = ws.get_Range(from,to);

Range findRng = rng.Find("Sep-08",Missing.Value,XlFindLookIn.xlValues,Missing.Value,Missing.Value,XlSearchDirection.xlNext,False,False,Missing.Value);
```

You can find the Microsoft example at [How to automate Excel by using Visual C# to fill or to obtain data in a range by using arrays](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302096).

Comment: How do I get the value from each row of that found `findRange`?

Comment: @Si8 does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32360462/get-cell-value-in-excel-from-range help?