# c# console app read excel sheet and remove rows based on contents

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, console-application

I have been reading up on ways to read a CSV File in C#  and I have heard that it is really complicated. What I am looking to do is have a console read a csv and if there are cells in column A that contain 123 it will delete all rows with a cell in column A with 123. BUT, as it does this all.. I need it to save to ANOTHER excel file so I have the original file as well. This is what I have to read the file.

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
Excel.Range range;

string str;
int rCnt = 0;
int cCnt = 0;

xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("123abc.csv", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into either the [EPPlus library](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) - You could use that to read in the Excel sheet and then do your manipulation fairly easily. Or use things such as Linq to Excel. There are lots of questions / info about that already on SO, or look at [this introductory video](http://vimeo.com/7689508). Or you could query the sheet as a DataBase if it's in tabular format.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Reading is a bit more simple you can use: https://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/ and that makes it dead easy.

Writing back is a bit more complicated. If you can use the interop for excel.
[1]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4x1k99a.aspx

or

[2]
Open XML SDK 2.0
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854(office.14).aspx

After your edit, why not make a copy of the original, then edit and save the copy? Since you are already using Excel.ApplicationClass(), you can also use xlApp.Save("filename")

Here is how you can find things in excel:
[Excel.Range.Find method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621620/excel-range-find-method)